# Boost calling method from outside of class

Tags: boost, boost-asio, tcpclient

Let's see how simple of a question I can ask. I have:

```
void TCPClient::test(const boost::system::error_code& ErrorCode)
{
    // Anything can be here
}
```

and I would like to call it from another class. I have a global boost::thread_group that creates a thread

```
clientThreadGroup->create_thread(boost::bind(&TCPClient::test,client, /* this is where I need help */));
```

but am uncertain on how to call test, if this is even the correct way.

As an explanation for the overall project, I am creating a tcp connection between a client and a server and have a method "send" (in another class) that will be called when data needs to be sent. My current goal is to be able to call test (which currently has async_send in it) and send the information through the socket that is already set up when called. However, I am open to other ideas on how to implement and will probably work on creating a consumer/producer model if this proves to be too difficult.

I can use either for this project, but I will later have to implement listen to be able to receive control packets from the server later, so if there is any advice on which method to use, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: `client` expects 1 argument of type `error_code`, so you have to pass it to `bind`: `bind(&TCPClient::test,client,some_error)`.

Comment: [This](http://blog.think-async.com/2010/04/bind-illustrated.html) is an illustrated example that may help with understanding `bind`.

Comment: @IgorR. It is the error codes that I am having trouble with. If there is a guide to them and how to use them in this situation, I would greatly appreciate it, as I have been unable to find anything (probably since I don't specifically know what I am looking for).

Comment: @TannerSansbury: Thank's for this, it helped explain bind a little better, as all I had was what I had picked up by using it and changing what I had seen.

Comment: @IgorR. Well, after just taking what you said literally, I just declared 'boost::system::error_code some_error;' right before calling test and it works. Thank's for the push in the right direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
boost::system::error_code err;
clientThreadGroup->create_thread(boost::bind(&TCPClient::test,client, err));
```

This works for me. I don't know if it will actually have an error if something goes wrong, so if someone wants to correct me there, I would appreciate it (if just for the experience sake).

Comment: How does `test` function treat its `error_code` argument? If you pass default-constructed `error_code`, it means "no error" (`err == false`).

Comment: For this, I am going on an assumption that when called from something else (eg 'm_Socket.async_receive(boost::asio::buffer(m_RecieveBuffer, m_BufLen),boost::bind(&TCPClient::OnReceive, this, boost::asio::placeholders::error));' ) it will put an error in if there is a problem in the 'async_receive' section of code, so that way when it reaches 'OnReceive' it will have an error code to use. This assumption may be wrong, and it could just be a 'placeholder', but I was assuming it was replaced if there was an error.

Comment: `placeholders::error` is an alias for `_1` and designates the fist argument of the binder, i.e. `bind(&func, asio::placeholders::error)` creates a functor that accepts 1 parameter. This parameter is passed by the caller that invokes the functor, i.e. by asio completion handler dispatcher, when `async_receive` gets completed.

Comment: This explains it a lot better than anything else I found. Thank's for the help, I am sure I will be back asking another question soon.